# Swipe TableView or CollectionView horizontally by creating three xib files

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Is it possible to create three xib files of TableView or CollectionView, implement separate functions, and swipe three xibs horizontally?

We will implement webview on each xib.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly you want to swipe left and right to load more data? Maybe what you're looking for is a PageViewController?

Comment: Are you sure for C tag ? Objective-C is a different language than C

Comment: The existing code is TableView, so I would like to modify it so that it can be swapped without changing the UIV View. Is it impossible with the method in question?                      
If I need to solve it with PageViewController, TabBar and BottomBar are fixed and I want to swipe only the middle part (WebView). Is that possible?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. If you want to slide horizontally, you can use CollectionView, and then you want to put all three webviews in the cell?

Comment: Resolved using pageViewController! Thank you very much.